# Why would an AWS Lambda Alias only log the INIT_START event to CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an AWS Lambda function that is triggered via a Rest API Gateway. It logs to the `/aws/lambda/my-function` CloudWatch log group as expected.

I wanted to use provisioned concurrency, so set the API Gateway to invoke a Lambda Alias instead. The function is called and generates the expected response. It creates a new log stream with the function version number in the name instead of `[$LATEST]`, as expected, however the only event logged is the `INIT_START` when the provisioned Lambdas start up.

I tried invoking using a test event via the AWS console to eliminate API Gateway as an issue. Again, invoking the function directly works as expected, but the alias with the same event produces the expected response but does not log to CloudWatch.

I have tried widening the CloudWatch-related IAM permissions for the Lambda function’s execution role but that didn’t improve things (to `logs:CreateLogGroup/CreateLogStream/PutEvents` on `arn:aws:logs:*:*:*`).

I tried publishing a new version of my function to update the alias, ensuring my test changes were picked up.

**Edit 1:**
I added the `context` object to my returned response to confirm it is definitely my alias being called, and that the logging config looks correct:

```json
{
  "context": {
    "callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop": true,
    "functionVersion": "6",
    "functionName": "my-function",
    "memoryLimitInMB": "128",
    "logGroupName": "/aws/lambda/my-function",
    "logStreamName": "2023/03/08/[6]541834ec8f884588ba63e209f0be0789",
    "invokedFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:function:my-function:my-function",
    "awsRequestId": "e0812992-cf58-4a8b-b4a6-1ac0a91445b1"
  }
}
```

You can see there that the `invokedFunctionArn` is the alias - when testing the function directly there is only one `:my-function` on the end. Also when calling directly the `functionVersion` is `$LATEST`.

Comment: What exactly are you invoking, what version / alias? Sounds like your `INIT_START` is simply logged because your lambda is provisioned but no invocation ever reaches that provisioned lambda execution environment.

Comment: @luk2302 In the AWS console if I go to the Lambda section and navigate to my function’s Test tab and send it a test API Gateway event, I get the generated response from my function and it logs to the CloudWatch group. If I then navigate to its Aliases tab, select my alias, and repeat, it generates the response but does not log anything.

Comment: @luk2302 as per **Edit 1** to my original question, I added the `context` object to the function output and you can see it is the alias being invoked by my testing.

Comment: Check that you have at least the permissions in [AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole$jsonEditor).

Comment: @jarmod As part of my testing I broadened the permissions to grant those CloudWatch permissions, without success. It appears that the alias *can* log something because it logs the `INIT_START` event when the provisioned concurrency starts them up, but does not log during actual execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was not with my function and its logging, but I was looking at the most recent streams in the CloudWatch console sorted by “last event time”, and the timestamps do not appear to be updating.

I added the Lambda call `context` object to my response to confirm that the invocation was being made against my Lambda alias (see **Edit 1**) in the question.

When I returned to this later I noticed that this also included the `logStreamName` so went about inspecting that in the API.

I can see for example a log stream that has:

```
// log stream
lastEventTimestamp: Wed, 08 Mar 2023 21:50:45 GMT
lastIngestionTime:  Wed, 08 Mar 2023 21:50:46 GMT

// actual most recent event
timestamp:          Wed, 08 Mar 2023 21:52:09 GMT
ingestionTime:      Wed, 08 Mar 2023 21:52:10 GMT
```

These stale values above are being returned some 30 minutes after the actual event, but as per the documentation are “eventually consistent” and do eventually update.

The confusion was exacerbated by each direct invocation of the Lambda function creating a new log stream with up-to-date “last event” timestamps, versus the behavior when invoking via the alias described above giving stale “last event” timestamps.